# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment in Windows 10

Tags: java, windows-10

I'm getting an error when try to open a Java Program in Windows 10.

Below I post the output log from my program:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ff8bdd7466d, pid=5392, tid=5188
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_51-b16) (build 1.8.0_51-b16)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.51-b03 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [VBoxD3D9wddm.dll+0x466d]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

If someone can help me to find a solution for this, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Maybe reinstall Java with a newer version?

Comment: **VBoxD3D9wddm.dll** - you running Win 10 in VirtualBox or running other OSes in VirtualBox?

Comment: I just had the exact same issue, and GhislainCote's answer worked for me. I would suggest clarifying the question to include that the error happens in a virtual machine, specifically VirtualBox. I'd also recommend adding the VirtualBox tag. I tried making an edit, but it was rejected with claims that the question isn't _about_ VirtualBox - I would say it very much _is_, as not only does the problem consistently appear in VirtualBox, the answer actually has to do with modifying VirtualBox VM settings. Granted, the answer wasn't marked as accepted, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

1. Turn off the VM
2. In the settings of the VM, go into the "Display" section.
3. Uncheck "Enable 3D Acceleration"
4. Reboot